# If statement that works too good

Tags: bash, if-statement

I'm working on this script and it's doing it's job. But it's too good... I want it to send me the IP of the server to my email (I have a dynamic IP at the place where the server is) and log it to a file (AAA) as well. The problem is that if the IP is the same as it was before it will echo "same" as it should, but still sends the email while it shouldn't. Am I missing something super obvious here?

The script is work in progress.

```
#! /bin/bash

catvar=$(cat AAA |tail -1 |awk '{ print $2 }')
date=$(date +"%d-%m-%y")
add1=$(wget -qO- icanhazip.com)
sendIP=$(sendemail -f ... the whole syntax with sensitive data) 

#echo $sendIP
#echo $date
#echo $add1
#echo $catvar

#######It's sending me email in both cases. 
if [ "$catvar" != "$add1" ];
then echo $sendIP; echo "$date $add1" >> AAA; 
else echo same; 
fi
```

Comment: sendIP=$(sendemail -f ... the whole syntax with sensitive data) 

During this command, sendemail is already executed before your if/else conditions.

Comment: Please provide a [mre] so that we can reproduce the issue and test solutions. For example, instead of relying on files that we don't have, use the time or `$RANDOM`, and instead of sending an email, just `echo` something. That said, you probably want to make `sendIP` into a [function](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Functions.html#Shell-Functions).

Comment: Like I said the syntax itself contains sensitive data, but I can show you like a mock syntax: ```sendIP=$(sendemail -f sendersemail@outlook.com -o tls=auto -t reciver@email.com -u "Hello" -m $THIS2 -s smtp.office365.com:587  -xu sendersemail@outlook.com -xp thePassword) ``` If you want to try it forsyourself with gmail you need to enable less ecure apps. In outlook it worked, but then the account was locked and I had to unlock it with my phone number. 
My first guess thou the $sendIP is not a problem, like I said the script works. It just sends me email in both cases and I only want change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are *doing* the sending *before* checking the condition, here, in this line:

```sh
sendIP=$(sendemail -f ... the whole syntax with sensitive data)
```

If you want want to do the sending only when the IPs are different then move that line inside `if` block:

```sh
if [ "$catvar" != "$add1" ]; then
    sendIP=$(sendemail -f ... the whole syntax with sensitive data)
    echo $sendIP
    echo "$date $add1" >> AAA
else
    echo same
fi
```

Comment: Thank you all for contributing! 
It didn't work in the first place, but when I moved the sendIP line below the variables it did. I did it like this:
```echo $sendIP; echo "$date $add1" >> AAA;
sendIP=$(sendemail -f ... the whole syntax with sensitive data)
``` 
I ran few tests and it worked that way. 
Thank you all!